# Scala + Spark (standalone) + google cloud logging stackdriver

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

One of my data pipeline (written in Scala) is using spark standalone which installed on GCP VM's.

we are trying to redirect the logs to GCP stackdriver.

1. I changed Spark via log4j-over-slf4j to use logback instead of log4j.
2. I added all needed dependencies (logback classic/core + google cloud logging) to
   build.sbt and also to **spark executor/driver extraClassPath.**
3. added logback-executor.xml file to each executor

I see that spark is using logback:

> INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-executor.xml] at [file:/opt/Spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/logback-executor.xml]

But it seems that redirecting to google cloud is not working:
I'm always getting class not found error.
At first, it was regarding "Credentials.class" so I've added
"google-auth-library-credentials-0.26.0.jar" and "google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.26.0.jar" to executor extraClassPath.

Now, I'm getting the same but for "Payload" class.

can someone did the same and can tell what is the best way/approach to redirect spark executor logs to stack driver?

thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - are you trying to ingest some log file from the VM running spark into the Stackdriver ?

Comment: I'm trying to send executor logs to Stackdriver

Comment: What files have you modified ?